# How to get jQuery ui range slider selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery ui range slider http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range in which there are two values that are being get when sliding is done (selection of range is done) then how to get those values into jQuery variables and only after the range is being selected ? i have to make a ajax call after that i get those values . can anyone help me this that how to get those values only after the both range selection is completed ?

I'm using this jQuery ui function to initiate the slider

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({ 
        range: true, 
        min: 0, 
        max: 500, 
        values: [ 75, 300 ], 
        slide: function( event, ui ) { 
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] ); 
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            // when the user change the slider
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // when the user stopped changing the slider
            $.POST("to.php",{first_value:ui.values[0], second_value:ui.values[1]},function(data){},'json');
        }
    }); 
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + 
                        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) ); 
});
```

Comment: how to get both values seperate and i dnt wana use json i ll use $ajax any solution for tht

Comment: you can get them like you did in the slide function, so first value will be ui.values[0] and the second one will be ui.values[1]; I've just gave you an example about using ajax request, you can use your own script :)

Comment: thanks for the help friend .. got it . its running as i wanted :)

Comment: Welcome, glad to hear this :)